# selecting entire row in linq after groupby

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Suppose I have a table with 5 columns with ( col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5).

I am trying to use a linq query to group by 2 columns ( col_2, col_3)  and i have to select first record ordered by 4th column( col_4 ) and have to get entire row having all 5 column for all records I will get.

```
from abcd in Context.table
group abcd by new { abcd.col2, abcd.col2 }
   into temp orderby temp.orderby(x=> x.col_4)
   select ..
```

Here I am confused how to get that entire row value,

Also I am not sure if this ordering logic will work as I want

I am using EntityFramework, and I already have an entity type for that row, 
and I have created an object which is list of that class.

So it would be best if I can directly fetch the result in that object.

Comment: Is that typo...`group abcd by new { abcd.col2, abcd.col2 }`...? Probably `abcd.col2, abcd.col3` may come..?

Comment: My original table has more than 20 columns and i dont want to add each with same name as I have in data model class in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Each group is a collection of the original items, so you can use Linq methods like `OrderBy` and `First` on each group:

```
from abcd in Context.table
group abcd by new { abcd.col2, abcd.col3 }
   into temp 
select temp.OrderBy(x=> x.col_4).First()
```